# Is it possible to use magento performance toolkit with Magento 1.9.2?

Tags: php, magento, jmeter, magento-1.9, load-testing

Github link for [Magento performance toolkit](https://github.com/magento/magento-performance-toolkit) has folders for Magento Enterprise edition 1.12 to 1.14. I downloaded it as also the [Jmeter plugins Extras Set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasSet/) and then tried to load the benchmark.jmx from 1.14 folder. It gave various errors in log file when loading. What can I do to reduce these errors to see more of the test plan? I want to use this as template to develop my own script for Magento 1.9 testing.

> 2016/01/31 23:42:55 WARN  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Missing jar? Could not create kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.MergeResultsGui. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jmeterplugins/save/MergeResultsService 
>   2016/01/31 23:42:55 INFO  - jmeter.util.BSFTestElement: Registering JMeter version of JavaScript engine as work-round for BSF-22
>
> 2016/01/31 23:42:55 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, using default
>
> 2016/01/31 23:42:55 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/html is
>
> 2016/01/31 23:42:55 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xhtml+xml is
>
> 2016/01/31 23:42:55 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for application/xml is
>
> 2016/01/31 23:42:55 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/xml is
>
> 2016/01/31 23:42:55 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Parser for text/vnd.wap.wml is org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.RegexpHTMLParser
>
> 2016/01/31 23:42:55 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.WebServiceSamplerGui
>
> 2016/01/31 23:42:55 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.MenuFactory: Skipping org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.modifier.gui.ParamModifierGui
>
> 2016/01/31 23:42:56 INFO  - jorphan.exec.KeyToolUtils: keytool found at 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_71\bin\keytool'
>
> 2016/01/31 23:42:56 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder SSL Proxy will use keys that support embedded 3rd party resources in file F:\Tools\apache-jmeter-2.13\bin\proxyserver.jks
>
> 2016/01/31 23:42:56 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: Note: Sample TimeStamps are START times
>
> 2016/01/31 23:42:56 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.default.encoding is set to ISO-8859-1
>
> 2016/01/31 23:42:56 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.useNanoTime=true
>
> 2016/01/31 23:42:56 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleResult: sampleresult.nanoThreadSleep=5000
>
> 2016/01/31 23:43:16 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Default base='F:\Tools\apache-jmeter-2.13'
>
> 2016/01/31 23:43:16 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file: E:\TestFolder\Tools\magento-performance-toolkit-master\1.14\benchmark.jmx
>
> 2016/01/31 23:43:16 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new base='E:\TestFolder\Tools\magento-performance-toolkit-master\1.14'
>
> 2016/01/31 23:43:16 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Testplan (JMX) version: 2.2. Testlog (JTL) version: 2.2
>
> 2016/01/31 23:43:16 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file encoding UTF-8
>
> 2016/01/31 23:43:16 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties file version 1656252
>
> 2016/01/31 23:43:16 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Using SaveService properties version 2.8
>
> 2016/01/31 23:43:16 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: All converter versions present and correct
>
> 2016/01/31 23:43:16 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file: E:\TestFolder\Tools\magento-performance-toolkit-master\1.14\benchmark.jmx
>
> 2016/01/31 23:43:16 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Settings: Delete null: true Check: true Allow variable: true Save: false Prefix: COOKIE_
>
> 2016/01/31 23:43:17 ERROR - jmeter.gui.GuiPackage: Could not get GUI for kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.CorrectedResultCollector@5fdf156b java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.vizualizers.ThreadsStateOverTimeGui
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getGui(GuiPackage.java:212)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addComponent(JMeterTreeModel.java:153)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:129)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.addSubTree(GuiPackage.java:495)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:193)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:131)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:89)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> 2016/01/31 23:43:17 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addComponent(JMeterTreeModel.java:154)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:129)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.addSubTree(GuiPackage.java:495)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:193)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:131)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:89)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2):

Its embarrassing, but I must accept it. I should also have installed the [Jmeter Plugins Standard set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/StandardSet/) besides the [Jmeter Plugins Extra Set](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasSet/). Installing both sets managed to fix this issue with no errors in log while loading.